# How to check a record's state on a certain date in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, powerbi

I'm looking to query to find the status of a work item on a certain date?

I've seen that you can find the dates of changes however my intention is to be able to create a trend graph showing the trends of work item's by status, over the past year.

How I want to accomplish this is form a query that shows what the status of every work item is on a specific date (let's say the 15th of the month).

Is this currently possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that from my current OData feed that one of the tables available is WorkItemSnapshot. This is exactly what I was looking for as it takes a snapshot of every work item in our environment for every single day.

From there you can parse the data at your leisure in PowerBI.